# Server OS won't update

Tags: centos7

One of our server is stuck on OS version 3.10.0-1127.el7.x86_64. yum update reports no updates but the latest OS 3.10.0-1127.19.1.el7.x86_64 won't apply after a reboot.
All our servers correctly updated but that one.

Any idea on how to troubleshoot this further?

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you say it is "stuck"? What happened when you tried to update? You need to provide all relevant details.

Comment: All the updates files are in the /boot area but rebooting the system does not update it. It remains on the old version.

Comment: Did you try selecting the new kernel at the grub boot screen?

Comment: I wouldn't know how to even get that screen. I'm not a UNIX SA. Just merely running some yum updates on google VMs. I'll dig around though. Thanks